# Find the paragraph number glyph

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have document with  multilevel numbering of paragraphs. As I traverse the paragraphs in GAS how do I get the actual numbering on each paragraph.

Eg: 1,1.2,1.2.3 etc.

I tried ListItem but the ListId returned a string identifier.

Comment: In your situation, is this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69717921

Answer (score 0):

If you are only referring to `NUMBER` as glyph type, yes you can achieved it by using the [`ListItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item) method. The problem is the "dot" that is present in your numbers. I think this is because the only format that is supported are `BULLET`, `HOLLOW_BULLET`, `SQUARE_BULLET`, `NUMBER`, `LATIN_UPPER`, `LATIN_LOWER`, `ROMAN_UPPER`, and `ROMAN_LOWER`. As "dot" is not considered number, I think this is not just a simple code. I have found [this github post](https://gist.github.com/mengwong/f597d064366f555b5f4e), you could check if this could be a little help.

Comment: The dot numbering is not glyph. It's multi level numbering available from the toolbar.
The glyph type I can get. But I want is the number contained in the glyph.