# How to get value of List Items using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, listitem

I have google document which contains list items. Now I want to get the values of those list items. For example, document contains this:

1. Text New
2. Text Old

How can I get list items (1,2)?

I used the following code, but it just gives me an array of list item objects but not the values of these list items.

```
function docFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docBody = doc.getBody();
  var docText = docBody.getListItems();
 
   Logger.log(docText);
 
}
```

Comment: try this code `docText.forEach(function(item){ Logger.log(item.getText())}) `

Comment: I tried but It is getting text which is coming after list items.

Comment: `console.log([...docText.keys()])`?

Comment: It looks like Doc doesn't store these values anywhere. It recalculates them every time you change the list. Probably you have to repeat all these calculations to get these values. I wonder if there is a workaround?

Comment: @TheMaster script gave the following error to your code statement: 

**TypeError: Cannot find function keys in object**

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, I proposed a workaround for retrieving glyph as a try. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Roomi Try in v8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is not way to retrieve the values you are needing.**

Moreover, `ListItem` refers to the item in the list itself, not the `Glyph`.

The closest thing to getting the information you want is by using the `getGlyphType` which will return the type of glyph you are using, in this case `NUMBER`.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script ListItem Class - getGlyphType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#getglyphtype).

Comment: This is the output that I have already mentioned. The output should not be Item1, Item2, and Item3 rather it should be 1,2, and 3 which is itemlist in this case

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the glyph from the list items by searching the text.
- For example, when there is the following list,

  ```
    1. Text New
    2. Text Old
  ```
- By searching `Text New` and `Text Old`, you want to retrieve the glyphs of `1.` and `2.`.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the glyph cannot be directly retrieved. This has already been mentioned in the comment and the existing answer.

Fortunately, the glyph type can be retrieved by Google Document service. And, the glyph format can be retrieved Google Docs API. I thought that when these are used, a workaround might be able to be proposed. So, this is just my try. I'm not sure whether this method can be used for all situations. So please be careful about this.

#### Sample script:

This script uses Docs API. So [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set the searching texts in the list.
  // const searchText = ["One One One", "Two Two Two", "ii ii ii ii ii", "C", "Factory Floor"];

  // In this case, all list itmes are retrieved.
  const searchText = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getListItems().map(e => e.getText().trim());

  // This is an object for the numbers with the GlyphType. When you want to use more numbers and GlyphTypes, please add them.
  const numObj = {
    "NUMBER": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
    "LATIN_LOWER": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    "LATIN_UPPER": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    "ROMAN_LOWER": ["i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v", "vi"],
    "ROMAN_UPPER": ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI"],
    "GLYPH_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED": ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
    "noGlyphType": ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
  };

  // 1. Retrieve list object using Docs API.
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const listObj = Docs.Documents.get(doc.getId(), { fields: "lists" }).lists;

  // 2. Retrieve list items using Document service and create an object for searching the texts.
  const listItems = doc.getBody().getListItems();
  const obj = listItems.reduce((o, e) => {
    const listId = e.getListId();
    const glyphType = e.getGlyphType() || "GLYPH_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED";
    const nestingLevel = e.getNestingLevel().toString();
    const text = e.getText();
    if (o[listId]) {
      if (o[listId][nestingLevel]) {
        if (o[listId][nestingLevel][glyphType]) {
          o[listId][nestingLevel][glyphType].text.push(text);
        } else {
          o[listId][nestingLevel] = { [glyphType]: { text: [text], glyphFormat: listObj[listId].listProperties.nestingLevels[nestingLevel].glyphFormat, nestingLevel } };
        }
      } else {
        o[listId][nestingLevel] = { [glyphType]: { text: [text], glyphFormat: listObj[listId].listProperties.nestingLevels[nestingLevel].glyphFormat, nestingLevel } };
      }
    } else {
      o[listId] = { [nestingLevel]: { [glyphType]: { text: [text], glyphFormat: listObj[listId].listProperties.nestingLevels[nestingLevel].glyphFormat, nestingLevel } } };
    }
    return o;
  }, {});

  // 3. Search text and output an object for retrieving glyphs.
  const getRes = (obj, search, res = [], parents = []) => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        v = v.map(vv => vv.trim());
        const temp = search.filter(s => v.includes(s));
        if (temp.length > 0) {
          const parent = parents[parents.length - 1];
          res.push(temp.map(e => ({ search: e, k: parent.k == "null" ? "noGlyphType" : parent.k, idx: v.indexOf(e), glyphFormat: parent.v.glyphFormat, nestingLevel: parent.v.nestingLevel })));
        }
      } else if (typeof v == "object") {
        parents.push({ k, v });
        getRes(v, search, res, parents);
      }
    });
    return search.map(s => res.flat().filter(t => t.search == s)[0]);
  }
  const res = getRes(obj, searchText).map(e => {
    const count = [...e.glyphFormat].reduce((c, e) => e == "%" ? c + 1 : c, 0);
    return e ? e.glyphFormat.replace(/%([0-9]+)/g, (_, p, o) => count > 1 ? numObj[e.k][o == 0 ? Number(p) : e.idx] : numObj[e.k][e.idx]) : "Text was not found."
  });

  console.log(res);
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above script is run, all list items are retrieved and the glyphs are returned. And, for example, when your sample Document shown in the following image is used and `const searchText = ["One One One", "Two Two Two", "ii ii ii ii ii", "C", "Factory Floor"];` is used as the search texts,

[image]

the following result is obtained.

```
[ '1.', '2.', 'ii.', '(A)', '1.3' ]
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the method for identifying `I` of `I1.` and `I2.`. By this, the glyph of `Factory Floor` becomes `1.3`.

#### Note:

- In the current stage, in my proposed script, I couldn't find the method for identifying `I` of `I1.` and `I2.`. When I could find the method, I would like to update my sample script.
- This is just my try. I'm not sure whether this method can be used for all situations. So please be careful about this.
- When you want to retrieve the glyphs for all list items, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const searchText = ["One One One", "Two Two Two", "ii ii ii ii ii", "C", "Factory Floor"];
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const searchText = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getListItems().map(e => e.getText().trim());
    ```
- Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the glyph type of check box type cannot be retrieved.

#### References:

- [getListItems()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getlistitems)
- [Enum GlyphType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/glyph-type)
- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [NestingLevel](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents)

Comment: Appreciate your help. But how do we know which text we are searching? This text can be different.

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. About `But how do we know which text we are searching? This text can be different.`, how about the script of `console.log(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getListItems().map(e => e.getText()))`?

Comment: sorry but this line is giving syntax error:
`console.log(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getListItems().map(e => e.getText()))`

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your new question of `sorry but this line is giving syntax error: console.log(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getListItems().map(e => e.getText()))`, in your Google Apps Script project, you are using V8 runtime? If you don't use it, please modify it to `console.log(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getListItems().map(function(e) {return e.getText()}))` and test it again. I apologzie for my poor skill again.

Comment: @Roomi I think that if you don't use V8 runtime, when you run my answer, an error occurs. Before you run this script, when you save this script, an error might occur. So, when you test my proposed script, please enable V8 runtime and test it.

Comment: You are right. I enabled V8 and it executed but the output is all the text excluding list items only.

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd question, I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, the output value is like `[ '1.', '2.', 'ii.', '(A)', '1.3' ]`. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand `but the output is all the text excluding list items only.`, can you provide the detailed flow for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Roomi In order to retrieve the glyphs of all list items, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.